# Send html with nonce for each script and style tag on each request

Tags: javascript, html, regex, express.js

This working code inserts a nonce attribute and value for each style and script tag inside an HTML file, for each GET request. It is using Express. `nonce1` and `dirViews` are already defined. `limiter` is for rate limiting and is a node module found on npm.

```
//on get homepage
app.get('/', limiter.middleware(), function(req, res, next) {
    //send an edited index.html containing nonces
    fs.readFile(dirViews+'/index.html', 'utf8', function(err, html){
        let newHTML = html.replace(/<script/g, '<script nonce="'+nonce1+'"').replace(/<style/g, '<style nonce="'+nonce1+'"');
        res.send(newHTML);
    });
});
```

I am unsure if this is the correct way to do this (set nonce attributes on each GET request), and whether my code follows best practices.

Comment: please can you make a suggestion for improving my question, since it was downvoted? I have already read /help/how-to-ask etc.

Comment: Does your code actually work? As in, it accomplishes the task you mean it to?

Comment: yes it does....

Answer (score 4):

> I am unsure if this is the correct way to do this (set nonces on each get)

[Yes, it is](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/#if_you_absolutely_must_use_it)

> Remember that nonces must be regenerated for every page request and they must be unguessable.

In terms of best practises, couple of things I'd recommend:

- Move your `nonce` manipulation into it's own middleware
- Cache your page content, don't read it from disk *every* time

The end result would look something like:

**csp.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const cache = new Map();

const getHtml = path => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  fs.readFile(path, 'utf-8', (err, contents) => {
    if (err) return reject(err);

    cache.set(path, contents);
    return resolve(contents);
  }));

const csp = page => async (req, res, next) => {
  const pagePath = path.join(dirViews, page);
  let html = cache.get(pagePath);
  if (!html) {
    html = await getHtml(pagePath);
  }
  html = html.replace(/<script/g, `<script nonce="${nonce1}"`)
    .replace(/<style/g, `<style nonce="${nonce1}"`);
  res.send(newHTML);
}

export default csp;
```

**app.js**

```
app.get('/', limiter.middleware(), csp('index.html'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully the response by James is sufficient for your concern about best practices. I did notice some redundancy in that snippet of Javascript.

Specifically, the line that handles adding the nonce attribute to the *script* and *style* tags could be simplified:

> ```
> let newHTML = html.replace(/<script/g, '<script nonce="'+nonce1+'"').replace(/<style/g, '<style nonce="'+nonce1+'"');
> ```

Since it already uses regular expressions (e.g. `/<script/g`), a [capturing group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-capturing-parentheses) could be added with the two cases for tag names: (i.e. `script` or `style`): `(script|style)` combined with an [OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-or) (i.e. `|`), and refer to that value using a [back-reference](http://webreference.com/js/column5/values.html) (i.e. `$1` for the first captured group) when adding the nonce attribute (in the replacement string parameter).

See a demonstration of this in the snippet below (should be portable to NodeJS).

```js
const html = document.head.innerHTML;
const nonce1 = 'blablabla12125125';
const newHTML = html.replace(/<(script|style)/g, '<$1 nonce="' + nonce1 + '"');
console.log(newHTML);
```

That way there is only one call to [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). While it might not save much processing time or power, it can at least make the line shorter and hopefully easier to read. In addition, if there was a need to add the attribute to additional tags, that tag name could easily be added to the expression in the capturing group.

Also notice that `newHTML` is declared with the `const` keyword instead of `let` because there is no need for reassignment. It is a good habit to use `const` by default and switch to `let` when re-assignment is deemed necessary.

Comment: Use of capture group definitely better :)

Comment: It is not using best practices, use stream instead of readFile into memory